# UnicodeEncodeError with django: inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, django, apache

I deployed a project on webfaction with djanog. All went fine until recently, when all of a sudden I started to get this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 64-68: ordinal not in range(128)
The url is with Russian characters. But the matter is, when I restart Apache, there is no error any more. So it is kind of difficult for me to pin the error.

Comment: Do you get this error when trying this with the built-in Django server (perhaps somewhere offline)?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't correctly configured django. See http://urfuclub.ru/blog/django-uwsgi-unicodeencodeerror-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/

Comment: Perhaps. I'll check it out. But I can't get why it is ok with cyrillics WHEN I restart apache??? It's production server.

Comment: guess, I got it to work - see my own answer, if interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#if-you-get-a-unicodeencodeerror

Most likely you need to ensure that UTF-8 is set as the lang locale for the environment Apache runs under.

Otherwise you need to ensure you handle Unicode issues in your code yourself where appropriate.

Comment: Can not control Apache (it's Webfaction's). So, for your second option I just ensured that all urls are unicode (see my own answer's comment to my question).

Comment: The startup of Apache under Web Faction is controlled via a script which is created under the account which is created for you when you select that it should be used. In other words you should be able to modify the script as necessary. Dig around in the apache2/bin of the specific site application directory created under ~/webapps. Specifically, look at the apachectl script and see if it still honours the 'envvars' file in same directory, that is, reads it for environment variables. If so, stick them in there.

Comment: It seams, I solved it via just making all urls plain ascii, but thanks for the insight, I'll check it for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because of filename or file contents cotains garbage collection or in another language (except english)..

So you can add `unicode()` for this. or check `NLTK` library of handling this situation.

Comment: yes, I had problems like this, but now it is a bit different: it is just inconsistent (sometimes I get the error; sometimes - not; on the same url).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to do with webfaction or my incorrect dealing with Apache: actually, I had a restart Apache command in my crontab. 
Found a similar question (dealing with Apache deliberately restarting), the webfaction guy suggested:

```
touch /path to /wsgi.py
```

instead of:

```
apache2/restart
```

after I replaced .../restart with the above line I have no more error messages.

Comment: Unfortunately, again the same Unicode error I got... Just changed for unicode in url; seems to stay stable for a few days. If interested, I used SLUGIFY = 'uuslug.slugify' setting in Mezzanine settings. (and installed uuslug, of course)